# meta refresh seo issue and pause on click of form field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have a page which is being refreshed every 30 seconds and new random contents are presented. i am using meta tag to refresh the page but recently i came across one article which says that meta refresh is not seo friendly so please tell what is seo friendly for refreshing the page.

```
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;url=http://xyyyyyyy.com/testn.php">\
```

in addition in my page when users tries to give his comment the page refreshes as per 30 second rule so is there any way i can pause refresh once the user try to type something in form so that user can give his view in comment.

this is my simple form

```
     <form action="http://xtsss.com/testee.php" method="post" id="pc_form">
    <p>

       <div><input type="text" rows="15" style="width:800px" name="message" id="pc_message"></div>
       </p>
        <p>
       <input type="hidden" value="644" name="pid">

            <input type="hidden" value="Comment" name="submit" id="pc_submit">
            </p>
  </form>
```

Comment: _“a page which is being refreshed every 30 seconds and new random contents are presented”_ – then search engines should not index that page at all! Because if they get presented random piece of content __X__ at the time they visit it and index it, and me searching for __X__ lists your page as a match, but when I go to your page I get presented random piece __Y__ instead, it is useless for me as a search result for __X__. So either tell search engines to not index that page at all – or stop serving _random_ content.

Comment: @CBroe sorry from my part it presents random image but the link gets changed every 30 seconds and for any specific link same image will be rpoesented sry for not being clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `div` tag to refresh content.

```
<div id='containt-refresh'></div>
```

```
let interval = setInterval(loadContentRandom, 30000);

function loadContentRandom(){
    let xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("containt-refresh").innerHTML=restoreHtml(escapeHtml(xmlhttp.responseText));
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","thePageHtml.html?"+Math.floor(Math.random()*1000001)+"",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: i am trying to do it in different way for example if $test is numric it will refresh or if $test is char it will show false how can i do this in php

Comment: can u plz help how to do this

Comment: Maybe this:
`<?php if(is_numeric($test)){ ?>

<script>loadContentRandom();</script>

<?php }elseif(is_string($test)){ ?>

<script> 
document.getElementById("containt-refresh").innerHTML="FALSE"; </script>

<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Suggest taking out the meta refresh and isolating the part of the page in which you would like random content to appear. Then you can use a jquery or javascript plugin to swap in content.

Comment: Yes, definitely. http://www.seroundtable.com/meta-refresh-no-google-13737.html  And as you can see, it hampers usability too. People don't like the whole page refreshing so fast, especially when the page has interactivity like your form.

Comment: ok agreed and i will remove meta tag but is there any safe way to refresh the page for example slide show etc where the form will be paused if user is typing in form

Comment: You could google for a jquery carousel. E.g., this one is good: dev7studios.com/plugins/caroufredsel/‎ .

Comment: i am trying to do it in different way for example if $test is numric it will say ok or if $test is char it will show false how can i do this in php